# Slider control missing?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a weird problem. I used the Slider control in my C# in the past, but now its missing.
I can't find System.Windows.Controls in my References list, and when I try to add it, it won't show in the '.NET' tab. Its even more weird becase I don't think any other control is missing.
How can I bring my Slider control back?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I don't know what WPF is, but I use windows forms in my app

Comment: In WinForms, you gave TrackBar control similar to Slider. If you want to use Slider control anyway, then use WPF.

Answer (score 18):

You can try this:

1. Right click on the Toolbox and select "Choose Items..." from the context menu.
2. In the ".NET Framework Components" tab, check if TrackBar is selected.

[image]

And if is not selected, you should select it.

MSDN link:

WinForms TrackBar:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @user1814575, if it is solved then mark the answer as solution

Comment: In VS2015, instead of right-clicking the Toolbox, it is under the Tools menu. But before going that far, I had better used the search box of the Toolbox, because Trackbar already was enabled, but not in Common Controls.

Comment: @user1814575 marking the answer as the solution would earn you 2 points. For you that's 30 percent up :-)